# What verb should I use instead of "[a city/territory/country] has on its land"?

Tags: word-request

> The region [verb] the largest lithium producer in the country.

What verb could I use? I know 'boast' but I need something neutral. Yes, I know I can simply use 'have' but no, I want something better, 'have' is too basic. 'Own' and 'possess' refer to the proprietary relationship between a person/organization and some asset. The plant implied in the question, on the other hand, could be owned by a foreign company. As I said in the title, I want a word to replace clumsy "has on its land".

Comment: I've reopened this question, although I believe the best answers will suggest rephrasing slightly rather than simply giving you a verb to put in that blank space.

Comment: Sergey - Whichever verb you end up choosing, it needs to be singular to match the singular noun "region" - e.g. "... region has" or "... region boasts".

Comment: @TechnoCat Of course, I know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an English professor, I can think of no better option than the term "**hosts**" suggested by @Technocat.  That is the perfect word, for reasons set out in Technocat's answer and in his/her subsequent comments.

You are certainly NOT correct in your belief that the dictionary definition precludes the term "hosts" being only for events; you are misunderstanding what the dictionary says.  You need only refer to the examples provided by Technocat to prove that the term is not only correct but in widespread usage.

The term **"is home to**" - suggested by Swaggy P - is a great option in some cases, but may or may not be appropriate, depending on the facts of the case.

Normally the term "home" is used to refer only to a company's headquarters, which are also often called the company's "home base".

For instance,

> "Cupertino, California, is home to Apple Inc ..."

is well understood to imply that this is the global headquarters.

Using the specific example you gave, both of the following are technically correct, but they have different meanings.

> "The region hosts the country's largest lithium producer."

This means only that the region's largest lithium producer has a presence in that region.  It does not preclude the possibility that the producer has a headquarters somewhere else.

> "The region is home to the country's largest lithium producer."

This variant has a very specific meaning: that the producer's **home base** is in that region.

Comment: "you are misunderstanding what the dictionary says" Please, elaborate

Comment: By 'producer' I meant a physical plant/mill, not a legal entity

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - If you re-read the responses from Technocat, the answers are all there.  Also, try doing the Google search suggested: there are literally thousands of examples of what you consider to be invalid.  Those examples are in publications from top publishing firms and are easy to follow.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - It doesn't matter whether the object is a "physical plant/mill" or a company, a factory, a species of plant, a group of people, a national park, ..... the term "hosts" is appropriate in all of them.  I can only suggest again that you learn from actual English usage - in other words, do as Technocat suggests.  Enter "The region hosts" into a Google search, and study the thousands of examples provided there from actual websites and publications.

Comment: What did you mean by me "misunderstanding what the dictionary says"?

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest *is home to*:

> The region is home to the largest lithium producer in the country.

I find it more neutral than 'boast' and it doesn't imply ownership as strongly as 'possess' or 'own' do.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for "**hosts**" if you wish to use just a single verb and also want the sentence to sound eloquent and professional.

> "The **region hosts** the largest lithium producer in the country."

The benefit of "hosts" is that it makes no assumptions about the nature of the ownership - i.e. it does not contain the proprietary implications of "own" or "possess".

If you were willing to make the sentence longer, another option would be the following.

> "The **region's rich economic resources include** the largest lithium
>   producer in the country.".

Comment: I considered using the verb 'host', but the dictionary didn't support my suggestion (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/host)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - Your dictionary link **does** support it.  Have a look at the section starting "TRANSITIVE VERB" and select "More examples".  There you will see, for instance, "‘All but one of the 25 largest cities in the U.S., and two-thirds of the next 25, host these projects.’ or '‘The city also plans to host four free or low-cost spay-and-neuter clinics throughout the year, Fusco said.’"

Comment: Further, as someone who has authored hundreds (or more) of business and scholarly reports and publications, I can assure you that the word suits the sentence very well.  It's the sort of term an educated native speaker would use.

Comment: Finally, I also support (and upvoted) the answer by @swaggy_p.  His suggestion to use "is home to" is a very good.

Comment: According to the entry, only an event or TV/radio program can be an object. In other words, not a physical thing

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev -  If you want to learn to write English eloquently and professionally, then you should take the advice of educated native speakers.  If you don't want to listen to the advice of experts, then you should not post questions in this forum and instead just read dictionaries.

Comment: Finally, if you don't believe me about the term "hosts" being appropriate for a business in a region, then enter "The region hosts " (with the quotes) into a Google search.  Here are the first three that popped up when I did that search.

Comment: Example 1: "**The region hosts** WarrnamboolCheese & Butter, the oldest dairy
company in Australia,  along with Bulla Family Dairy, Fonterra and ....  Source: http://www.invest.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0018/325611/3-GSC_v18F.pdf

Comment: Example 2: "Besides these two medium-sized firms, the Swedish part of **the region hosts** about 35 other DBFs of varying size and age.  A large share of the companies ..." .  Source: Business Networks in Clusters and Industrial Districts, avail at https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Ug1pfIVU8yEC&pg.

Comment: Example 3: "**The region hosts** 61 publicly-owned, public-use airports ...".  Source: Scientific Assessment of the Effects of Global Change on the United States, avail at https://books.google.com.au/books?id=exSRYgA8tWEC.

Comment: There are thousands of other such examples on Google, which you can see for yourself.

Comment: No, I shouldn't. You should check out the second definition of the word 'boast': https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/boast

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *to possess* would be an option, however I think *to hold* seems me an either natural and elegant alternative.

Thus, `[The region] holds the largest lithium producer in the country` could be your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*X **is (located)** / **can be found** in the region* should work, although it depends a bit on the surrounding text.